# How can i show/hide navbar based on scroll position?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a solution to apply a scroll based animation to my navbar. When i scroll down or up, i want to hide/show the navbar with a scroll animation. After some research i always find only solutions like the following.

```js
var lastScrollTop; // This Varibale will store the top position

navbar = document.getElementById('navbar'); // Get The NavBar

window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
 //on every scroll this funtion will be called
  
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  //This line will get the location on scroll
  
  if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop){ //if it will be greater than the previous
    navbar.style.top='-80px';
    //set the value to the negetive of height of navbar 
  }
  
  else{
    navbar.style.top='0';
  }
  
  lastScrollTop = scrollTop; //New Position Stored
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container{
  background:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497250681960-ef046c08a56e') no-repeat center center;
  height:170vh;
}
#navbar{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
  border-radius:0 0 30px 30px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  
  /*Define a height for NavBar*/
  height:80px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /*and a transition time for a smooth appearence*/
  
}

footer{
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <navbar id="navbar">
    <h1>NAVBAR<h1>
  </navbar>
</div>
<footer>
  <h3>End of the Page</h3>
</footer>
```

If you scroll down or up, a css class or a style definition is applied to the navbar. But **i want to show/hide the navbar, based on how much you scrolled**. Say you open the page, the navbar is visible `top: 0px`, so you need to scroll maybe `80px` down and every pixel you scrolled down, the navbar will be hidden pixel by pixel - so we get  a nice scroll animation, instead of apply a property. The same happens when we scroll back up, only in reverse of course.

The idea comes from medium.com. If you open a post in mobile view, you can see a footer overlay which will be hide/show based on how much you scrolled:

[image]

How can i create the same kind of animation? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS `position: sticky;`?

Comment: Why do you want to calculate height?

Comment: Your condition will apply whatever css you put when ``` if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop)``` this scrollTop is greater than you lastscroll it doesn't need to be scrolled ```80px``` or any specific value.

Comment: @Nikkkshit please take a look at this Medium post: https://medium.com/@johndyer24/creating-and-deploying-an-auto-updating-electron-app-for-mac-and-windows-using-electron-builder-6a3982c0cee6  in mobile view and pay attention to the element in the footer area. When you scroll up or down, it disappears or fades in, but based on how much you scroll. This is exactly the kind of animation I would like to have. Do you see what I mean now?

Comment: @Nikkkshit yes exactly as you saw it on the medium page. Could you help me to figure this out?

Comment: Sure, I will try

Comment: I have changed my answer please check it is that what you want?

Comment: @Nikkkshit thanks for your effort, but unfortunately this is still not my desired result. Please take a look at my question again. I have just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You have to change the value of scroll top.</s>

```js
…
// (1)
if (lastScrollTop == undefined) {
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
}

// (2)
if(scrollTop - lastScrollTop >= 80) { // if you've scrolled down 80px
    navbar.style.top='-80px';
    //set the value to the negetive of height of navbar 

    // (3)
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop; // New Position Stored

// (4)
} else if (lastScrollTop - scrollTop >= 80) { // if you've scrolled up 80px
    navbar.style.top='0';
    
    // (5)
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop; // New Position Stored
}
…
```

1. Since the lastScrollTop isn't being changed on every scroll, it needs to be set initially (when it has no value)
2. For example: If `scrollTop` is, 81, and `lastScrollTop` is 1, then `scrollTop - lastScrollTop` will be 80 (and the condition is true). That will work after you have scrolled down 80 px
3. Now that 80px has been reached, reset the property.
4. Similar logic to `(2)`, just reversed.
5. Same as `(3)`

I hope this helps!

P.S. You can change the value, 80, to any number you want.

## Edit:

This gets the distance between the last scroll and the current position, and changes the nav bar style based on that.

```js
const navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

            let lastScrollTop = 0;
            addEventListener("scroll", () => {
                // Current scroll position
                const scrollTop =
                    window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

                // check scroll direction
                const distance = scrollTop - lastScrollTop;
                const currentTop = parseInt(
                    getComputedStyle(navbar).top.split("px")
                );

                // Clamp value between -80 and 0
                let amount = Math.max(
                    Math.min(
                        currentTop +
                            (distance < 0
                                ? Math.abs(distance) // scrolling up
                                : -Math.abs(distance)// scrolling down
                                ) * 40, // (1)
                        0
                    ),
                    -80
                );

                console.log(amount, currentTop, Math.abs(distance));

                navbar.style.top = `${amount}px`;

                lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
            });
```

```css
body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .container {
                background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497250681960-ef046c08a56e")
                    no-repeat center center;
                height: 170vh;
            }
            #navbar {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                background: blue;
                border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;

                /*Define a height for NavBar*/
                height: 80px;
                transition: 0.5s;
                /*and a transition time for a smooth appearence*/
            }

            footer {
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <navbar id="navbar">
                <h1>NAVBAR</h1>
            </navbar>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <h3>End of the Page</h3>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. This value can be changed to suit your needs — for reasons I couldn't figure out, I needed to add this in order to make it scroll fast enough.

I hope this can point you in the right direction!

Comment: thank you for your answer, but instead of reset the `top` property, i want to animate it based on how much you scroll.

Comment: Oh ok — I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thanks, please take a look at my updated question, it may helps

Answer (score 0):

- I have added class based upon this condition.

```js
if (!navbar.classList.contains("visiable")) {
      navbar.classList.add("visiable");
    }
```

-You can play with css values add more property and get as changes as you want.

```css
/*This are the one I have used to manipulate that effect*/
transform: translateY(-80px) scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
```

- and applied css to `.visiable` class to get that effect.

```js
var lastScrollTop; // This Varibale will store the top position

var navbar = document.getElementById('navbar'); // Get The NavBar

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  //on every scroll this funtion will be called

  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  //This line will get the location on scroll

  if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) { //if it will be greater than the previous
    if (!navbar.classList.contains("visiable")) {
      navbar.classList.add("visiable");
    }
    //set the value to the negetive of height of navbar 
  } else {
    if (navbar.classList.contains("visiable")) {
      navbar.classList.remove("visiable");
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = scrollTop; //New Position Stored
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497250681960-ef046c08a56e') no-repeat center center;
  height: 170vh;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  /*Define a height for NavBar*/
  height: 80px;
  transform: translateY(-80px) scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.9s;
  /*and a transition time for a smooth appearence*/
}

#navbar.visiable {
  transform: translateY(0px) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <navbar id="navbar" class="visiable">
    <h1>NAVBAR
      <h1>
  </navbar>
</div>
<footer>
  <h3>End of the Page</h3>
</footer>
```

Comment: the effect is cool thanks, but you don't know, how can we get the same effect, using scroll position instead of applying a css class? that's why I asked the question, because I myself do not know how to calculate it :)

Comment: Just appy all this css using javascript

Comment: sorry, i don't want to use css to create this animation. I want to use `window.scrollY` to calculate the navbar top position to get the same effect when you scrolls, like this `navbar.style.top = window.scrollY * 100 + 'px'`